# Yocto build for intel, qt5 eglfs cant find /usr/lib/dri/

Tags: opengl, intel, yocto, mesa

I have been building yocto for x86_64 for the intel QM87 and i have an Qt5 application that i would like to run with -platform eglfs but it errors. im trying to make my image as small as possible so i do not want to install all of x11 or wayland. is there a way to install just the drivers i need. every time i run the app it errors saying it could not find

> /usr/lib/dri/i965_dri.so
>   /usr/lib/dri/kms_swrast.so
>   /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so
>   /usr/lib/gbm/gbm_gallium_drm.so

In my mesa.inc file i have added the packages

> PACKAGECONFIG ??= "egl gles dri gallium gallium-egl gallium-gdm \

my conf/local.conf contains

> EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES = " debug-tweaks ssh-server-openssh "  > CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL += " libgles2-mesa "
>
> PREFERRED_PROVIDER_jpeg = "libjpeg-turbo"
>   PREFERRED_PROVIDER_jpeg-native = "libjpeg-turbo-native"
>
> IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " gcc g++ binutils libgcc libgcc-dev libstdc++ libstdc++-dev libstdc++-staticdev \
>   autoconf automake ccache chkconfig glib-networking glibmm \
>   packagegroup-core-buildessential pkgconfig  \
>   boost cmake zlib glib-2.0 \
>   ruby \
>   cpufrequtils \
>   nano \
>   gdb \
>   gstreamer \
>   gst-meta-video \
>   gst-plugins-base-app \
>   gst-plugins-base \
>   gst-plugins-good \
>   gst-plugins-good-rtsp \
>   gst-plugins-good-udp \
>   gst-plugins-good-rtpmanager \
>   gst-plugins-good-rtp \
>   gst-plugins-good-video4linux2 \
>   openssh-sftp-server \
>   qtbase-fonts \
>   qtbase-plugins \
>   qtbase-tools \
>   qtdeclarative \
>   qtdeclarative-plugins \
>   qtdeclarative-tools \
>   qtdeclarative-qmlplugins \
>   qtmultimedia \
>   qtmultimedia-plugins \
>   qtmultimedia-qmlplugins \
>   qtsvg \
>   qtsvg-plugins \
>   qtsensors \
>   qtimageformats-plugins \
>   qtsystems \
>   qtsystems-tools \
>   qtsystems-qmlplugins \
>   qtscript \
>   qt3d \
>   qt3d-qmlplugins \
>   qt3d-tools \
>   qtwebkit \
>   qtwebkit-qmlplugins \
>   qtgraphicaleffects-qmlplugins \
>   qtconnectivity-qmlplugins \
>   qtlocation-plugins \
>   qtlocation-qmlplugins \
>   cinematicexperience \
>   cairo pango fontconfig freetype pulseaudio dbus \
>   alsa-lib alsa-tools alsa-state alsa-utils-alsaconf \
>   i2c-tools \
>   libjpeg-turbo \
>   mesa \
>   libva-intel-driver \
>   "
>
> DISTRO_FEATURES_remove = " x11 jpeg "
>   DISTRO_FEATURES += " wayland x11-base opengl pam"
>
> BB_NUMBER_THREADS = "16"
>   PARALLEL_MAKE = "-j 16"
>
> QT_PROVIDER = "qt5"
>
> PACKAGECONFIG_GL_pn-qtbase = "gles2 linuxfb"
>   PACKAGECONFIG_DISTRO_pn-qtbase = "icu"
>
> PACKAGECONFIG[qtbase] = "-nomake tests -opengl desktop"
>
> DISTRO_FEATURES += " \
>   ipv4 ipv6 libc-backtrace libc-big-macros libc-bsd libc-cxx-tests libc-catgets libc-charsets libc-crypt \
>   libc-crypt-ufc libc-db-aliases libc-envz libc-fcvt libc-fmtmsg libc-fstab libc-ftraverse \
>   libc-getlogin libc-idn libc-inet libc-inet-anl libc-libm libc-locales libc-locale-code \
>   libc-memusage libc-nis libc-nsswitch libc-rcmd libc-rtld-debug libc-spawn libc-streams libc-sunrpc \
>   libc-utmp libc-utmpx libc-wordexp libc-posix-clang-wchar libc-posix-regexp libc-posix-regexp-glibc \
>   libc-posix-wchar-io \
>   libgl1-mesa-dri \
>   "

Comment: Everything in /usr/lib/dri/ is in the `mesa-megadriver` package so start by adding that to your image.

Comment: Thank you, that solves 2 of the 4, and i made mesa_%.bbappend that gives i965. but it seems yocto fido doesnt give gbm_gallium_drm.so anymore. how can i add that to my image?